# RPC can not accept string?

Tags: string, rpc

I'm making a game. The client sends an RPC to the server saying "move me to this instance". It was working fine until I restarted my computer and reloaded the nodes/database server etc. But now if I give it a string it won't work, if I don't give it a string and declare it in the RPC which does the EXACT SAME THING, it works fine. The string in question is zoneId.

This is the RPC:

```
[RPC]
IEnumerator FindGameServerReq(uLobby.LobbyMessageInfo info, string zoneId)
{
    Debug.Log("Client " + info.sender + " requested joinable game server.");
    Debug.Log("Zone ID: " + zoneId);

    var req = _instanceMgr.GetInstance(zoneId);
    yield return req.WaitUntilDone();

    var gameServerEndPoint = req.GetGameServerEndPoint();
    Debug.Log("Informing " + info.sender + " to join game server " + gameServerEndPoint);
    uLobby.Lobby.RPC("FindGameServerResp", info.sender, gameServerEndPoint);
}
```

This is how I call the RPC:

```
uLobby.Lobby.RPC("FindGameServerReq", uLobby.LobbyPeer.lobby, "town");
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception: Can't read from BitStream because the type safe code 'String' should have been 'Object'
uLink.BitStream.#=qaJMtkufwOBTmus4Sj1oTtg== (BitStreamTypeCode #=q0kejgO9k7qY8elenFktRag==)
uLink.BitStream._ReadObject (uLink.BitStreamCodec codec, System.Object[] codecOptions)
#=qEcomxFqHWOojBhw7H8BPzzZhTr1DAnoBEQ62wyTQ$_s=.#=qGXSr2kjU4f7Ppc8kLs_Ngw== (uLink.BitStream #=qgXeDfPNYYMJmwReOvN7L$g==, System.Object #=quKCAMLPDCdyzEzH7UPZtmg==)
#=qI8pUof4AE4hEbRq3kz45z_BPBVKqHSPhJs4bLixooWQ=.#=q0c9j_kaqqCWqjUzT6CDHZQ== (uLink.BitStream #=qQILAgzJGastvZ9EIjYcBAA==, System.Object #=qIMGdUjbLteWVoYoL7pJv6Q==)
uLobby.Lobby.#=qn$OneteGV_YoF5_9aIgusg== (.#=q$FieuT6o10Me2og7rTqd9Q== #=qkk5WAgkwWtcicPRsMf4WhQ==, Boolean #=qHhcjKXvQyV_PqtKYVSZAqA==)
```

Obviously the string should be a string not an object. Please help, I've tried on unity answers but it's almost impossible to get an answer there because their website is a bit of an oxymoron.

Comment: This problem has existed for days and still I can't find a solution, can someone please help. I left the lobby server running for over a day and it worked again, until I restarted it, now the problem is back.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the order of the parameters this way:

```
IEnumerator FindGameServerReq(string zoneId, uLobby.LobbyMessageInfo info)
```

the LobbyMessageInfo must be the last parameter in your RPC